# Golang: right way to store map structure in lru cache

Tags: performance, caching, go

I have a structure like: `map[key]value`, and I want to store it in `"github.com/golang/groupcache/lru"` by a string key, say, the `cacheKey`.

Here is my question:

I found whenever I want update the cached item, I need to `Get` it first:

```
item := cache.Get(cacheKey)
if v, ok := item[key]; ok{
    item[key]=new_value
    cache.Add(cacheKey, item)
}
```

Is it right way to do this?

Or, as some of people suggested, I need to re-design my structure to make sure I can do `cache.Add(cacheKey, item)` whenever I want to update it.

Or, I should even use a combined key like `cacheKey_key` to store that item?

Comment: I can't say I understand the question. Do you want to use map as the  key and something else as a value?

Comment: @Schultz9999 I want to store a map in cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above will work. I looked at the source of LRU cache you refer to. Here are my notes:

- whatever you decide, make sure access to this LRU is thread-safe if you plan to use it within goroutines.
- you may store `*map` instead of plain `map`, which would eliminate a need to call add.
- if it's ok to add to the map with override, skip presence check (`if v, ok...`)

So having said that, here is what it becomes:

```
m sync.Mutex
m.Lock()
defer m.Unlock()
cache.Get(cacheKey)[key] = new_value
```

If you elaborate on what sort of data you are planning to store, we may try to come up with an alternative solution.

Comment: My data is like `type PredicateMap map[uint64]HostPredicate`, but it can **not** be override, thus makes storing a `*map` not work.

Comment: Accepted as answer. Eventually, I found that storing a index saves me a lot time.